# Byte array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a a php string:

e.g. df299cc4cda279e4d7344b42a8006d94488c753f

This is representing a 20 bit HEX output. How would I select the n'th byte? For example if I select the 3rd one it should return 9c.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bytes = str_split($string, 2);
echo $bytes[2];
```

Or you may want to convert the string to actual binary using [`hex2bin`](http://php.net/hex2bin), then echo the index `[2]` of the string, possibly converting back to hex for output.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [chunk_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) or [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and get a result like:

```
$string = "df299cc4cda279e4d7344b42a8006d94488c753f";
$bytes = str_split($string, 2); 
$yourByte = $bytes[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Given $n = byte number (3 in your example) and $data = string with hex output,

```
return substr($data, ($n - 1) * 2, 2)
```